# Python Dictionary KeyError and Multiple Dictionaries

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, try-catch, keyerror

I have 3 dictionaries

```
a = {1:'this' ,2:'is' ,3:'an' ,4:'example'}
b = {4:'this' ,5:'is' ,6:'example'}
c = {7:'this' ,8:'is'}
```

and this

```
for i in range(10):
    print a[i] ,b[i] ,c[i]
```

it causes a KeyError, **How do i know which of the three dictionaries raised the error?** is there any simple way.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: split it into multiple lines... or use a debugger

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do it with your current code, because Python exception tracebacks are line-based, not token-based.

Instead, you could use the `.get()` method on the dictionaries, and check each result to see if it's `None` (or if the values could actually be `None` normally, provide your own alternate default).

```
for i in range(10):
    # if a key is missing in a, x will be None, etc.
    x, y, z = a.get(i), b.get(i), c.get(i)
```

Alternatively, you could just break your `print` statements up into multiple lines:

```
for i in range(10):
    print a[i],
    print b[i],
    print c[i]
```

And then you could wrap them in individual `try` blocks as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Amber but my original code is much more complex and involves math operations such as divisions and multiplication i cannot seperate them into multiple lines. Any more ideas?

Comment: Use intermediate variables, rather than trying to inline all of the lookups.

Comment: great idea will be back with results.

Comment: Thank you Amber! although it doesn't solve the problem, it has now become easier to debug for me! :)